# Reconocer Si 2 Imágenes Son Iguales

Tags: c#

Deseo Reconocer si 2 imágenes son `iguales` para conocer imágenes duplicadas me explico tengo dos imágenes con una `ruta especifica` y quiero saber si esas 2 imágenes son las mismas con codigo de C#, Ya intentado pero no me a funcionado lo que intento realizar, no me importa si tengo que utilizar librerías externas solo quiero comparar las imágenes.

**¿Es posible de realizar?**

Comment: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/17494328-ef0c-dc83-1bc3-907b7b75039f.htm uTILIZA LA LIBRERIA DE AFORGE

Comment: Nose como utilizarla... no tiene instrucciones claras para llamar la función

Comment: Utiliza su Metodo compare,

Comment: Me muestra errores....

Comment: Por favor. Lo que intentes (el código relevante) va en la pregunta, igual que los errores. No nos dice mucho que comentes "me muestra errores" y hace más difícil ayudarte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque no es exactamente una comparación de imágenes, quizá te resulte más sencillo si comparas las cadenas MD5 calculadas a partir de los archivos de imagen en lugar de cada uno de los pixels de la imagen.

Si las cadenas son iguales con un 99,99% de probabilidad las imágenes serán iguales.

Puedes probar con esta función para obtener el MD5 de un archivo:

```
public string GetMd5(string fileName)
{
    using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(stream));
        }
    }
}
```

y ya sólo tendrías que comparar los resultados:

```
if (GetMd5("bitmap1.png") == GetMd5("bitmap2.png"))
    Console.WriteLine("Son iguales");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Son diferentes");
```

Comment: Me muestra siempre que son iguales... ¿Que estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: Disculpa, escribí el código directamente y no me di cuenta que estaba devolviendo un array de bytes en lugar de una cadena. He modificado el código para que convierta el MD5 a Base64, ahora debería funcionarte.

Answer (score 1):

**Puede Resolver Esto...**

1- Crear una aplicación de consola

2- Importar `using AForge.Imaging;` y `using System.Drawing;`

3- Aquí para descargar la librería de [Aforge](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/aforge/AForge.NET%20Framework-2.2.5-(libs%20only).zip)

4- Descomprimir Archivo Rar

5- Luego en Visual Studio Agregar Referencia>Agregan  `AForge.Imaging.dll`(Esta en la carpeta Relase)

6- Luego Agregan este código en el proyecto

> Codigo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ruta = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap(ruta + "/image.jpg");
        Bitmap image2 = new Bitmap(ruta + "/imageCopia.jpg");

        ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0);

        TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(image1, image2);

        if (matchings[0].Similarity > 0.95f)
        {
            // Son Similares
            Console.WriteLine("Son Similares");
        }

        else
        {
            //No son similares
            Console.WriteLine("No Son iguales");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Boolean Compare(this Bitmap image1, Bitmap image2, double comparisionLevel, float threshold)
    {

        return new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(threshold)
            .ProcessImage(image1.To24bppRgbFormat(), image2.To24bppRgbFormat())[0]
            .Similarity >= comparisionLevel;
    }
```

Comment: Tiene el codigo completo? a mi me produce errores